# Error: expected primary-expression before "__attribute__"

Tags: c, gcc

How to avoid following error:-

```
error: expected primary-expression before "__attribute__"
```

Code:

```
#define A(name) __attribute__(name)
```

If i use this macro as A(name) in my code, I am getting error as `expected primary-expression before "__attribute__"`

Comment: Do you talk about html attributes, or what?

Comment: this is my code. declaring like,#define A(name) __attribute__(name). If i print same macro in other file like printf("%s",A("Hello"));It is not printing like __attribute__(Hello). It is giving this error(expected primary expression).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`#define A(name) __attribute__((name))`

Since there is no code, I can't say if you are using it properly.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. __attribute__ gives an attribute to a structure or a function. For example, you can use `void my_func() __attribute__((noreturn))`. `printf("%s", __attribute((noreturn)));` makes absolutly *no* sense.

Comment: If you really want to print that in a printf, try: `#define A(name) "__attribute__((" name "))"`